# VBA places Webbrowser outside userform in Office2019

Tags: excel, vba, webbrowser-control

For years - in Office2013 - we are/were using several userforms with a webbrowser control (reference to Microsoft Internet Controls) to show pdf documents in the userform.

Since we migrated to Office2019, the webbrowser is shown outside the userform and placed behind the userform's parent window (i.e. Outlook or Excel). This happens when the macro is activated from a button on the ribbon.

But, when running the userform from the VBE with F5 (either straight from the form or via a macro in a module that loads/shows the form) it works like expected.

Does anybody have a clue where to look to solve this problem?

Code used in a userform to show the pdf file

```
Me.WebBrowser1.Navigate URL:="D:\file.pdf"
```

Code used in a module to show the userform

```
Sub MacroName()
   Load Userform
   Userform.Show
End Sub
```

Comment: A moment ago, I found this. Haven't tried it yet. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7dfc7185-b62d-41db-95fb-46d4ce670eb6/webbrowser-control-loads-outside-the-vba-userform-in-excel?forum=isvvba

Comment: no kb4345421 found on our computers. Still need to figure out to open a new userform

Comment: Thx for your reply. As far as I know Hwnd only exists in Word and Excel. Haven't tried your code for the Excel app yet, but for Outlook we are still searching for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to set the parent window for your user form instance. The [SetParent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setparent) changes the parent window of the specified child window.

```
Function SetFormParent(UF As MSForms.UserForm, _
    Parent As FORM_PARENT_WINDOW_TYPE) As Boolean
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' SetFormParent
' Set the UserForm UF as a child of (1) the Application, (2) the
' Excel ActiveWindow, or (3) no parent. Returns TRUE if successful
' or FALSE if unsuccessful.
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Dim UFHWnd As Long
Dim WindHWnd As Long
Dim R As Long

UFHWnd = HWndOfUserForm(UF)
If UFHWnd = 0 Then
    SetFormParent = False
    Exit Function
End If

Select Case Parent
    Case FORM_PARENT_APPLICATION
        R = SetParent(UFHWnd, Application.hwnd)
    Case FORM_PARENT_NONE
        R = SetParent(UFHWnd, 0&)
    Case FORM_PARENT_WINDOW
        If Application.ActiveWindow Is Nothing Then
            SetFormParent = False
            Exit Function
        End If
        WindHWnd = WindowHWnd(Application.ActiveWindow)
        If WindHWnd = 0 Then
            SetFormParent = False
            Exit Function
        End If
        R = SetParent(UFHWnd, WindHWnd)
    Case Else
        SetFormParent = False
        Exit Function
End Select
SetFormParent = (R <> 0)

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with VBA in Outlook in Office 365. 
Not sure if this will work for you or not, but my issue was resolved by going to Outlook Options > General. Then under "User Interface Options" for the setting "When using multiple displays" select the option "Optimize for compatibility"

Then restart outlook. The same option should be available in Excel too. Try and see if it works. It worked for me. I hope it works for you too.